# python:Using split strings

Tags: python, string, split, syntax-error

My problem is that I'm trying to modify a word in a file so I look for the word in the file loaded as a string and then rewrite the file with the new word and the split string.Except I can't seem to add the end of the file because I get a syntax error with the ':'. It must be a basic error I made but I can't find it. Can anyone help me ?

```
def modifier(aModif,nouvModif):
    #"""Permet de modifier un mot du dictionnaire"""
    #Qmodif = input("Quel mot voulez vous modifier ?")
    dico = open ('dico.txt','r+')
    texte= dico.read()
    print(type(texte))
    position=texte.index(aModif)
    dico.seek(0)
    dico.write(texte[:position]+ nouvModif + [(position + (len (aModif))): end])
    dico.close

modifier('blabla','ertddghdthdtqhdtheqhqtsgrgtetehfgh')
```

I tried to use it without the end after the ':' but still the same problem!

```
dico.write(texte[:position]+ nouvModif + [(position + (len (aModif))):])
```

Comment: why not use `dico.replace('blabla','ertddghdthdtqhdtheqhqtsgrgtetehfgh', 1 )` ?

Answer (score 0):

`[(position + (len (aModif))):]` is a slice which must be preceeded by an (¿ordered?) iterable.

For example `'abcdef'[3:]` is `'def'`, but `[3:]` all alone doesn't make much sense.

Maybe your `+` after nouvModif is the problem.

Comment: thanks but im french so can you describe awhat an iterable is ?

Comment: Lists, strings, tuples,... Whatever implements an `__iter__` method.

Comment: of course stupid me thanks very much i'll try that and keep you updated!

Comment: @user3154918 Do you want to replace the first occurrence of `aModif` or all?

Comment: just if all works properly the should only be one occurence. The problem wasn't the + but the fact that I had forgotten the 'code'texte'code' before the [ !